# What can I use to remember the difference between "well" and "good"?

Tags: grammar, differences, ambiguity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between “good” and “well”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5174/what-is-the-difference-between-good-and-well)

Okay, I actually have no idea when it's okay to say well or good but once again I vaguely remember a rule about them and I don't want to sound ignorant anymore or have that memory haunt me whenever people ask me how I'm doing.

Comment: What is the rule you vaguely remember?

Comment: The part I remember is that you have to be careful about using well and good. Something about "I've been well" vs. "I've been good".

Comment: Here's how to remember: If you are not good, Santa will bring you coal.  If you are not well, he will visit you in the hospital.  Sorry for the culturally narrow mnemonic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a grammar perspective: You use **well** when you need an *adverb*, and **good** when you need an *adjective*.  That's the big difference.

Use **well** to talk about how, or in what way something is done:

- *The house is well built.*
- *The dinner was well prepared.*

Use **good** when to talk about a noun or pronoun.  A **good** person, place or thing:

- *She is a good doctor.*
- *The dinner was good.*

Comment: _Well_ is also an adjective: _he was not a well man._

Comment: Yes, in the sense of health, which is different to the sense of the original question.