# What is the difference between "good" and "well"

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Most of the time, I use *good* and *well* interchangeably. However, on many occasions I would find *well* or *good* a misfit. Please suggest the proper usage.

Comment: I find it amusing that there's a 'noun' tag here, when in fact neither of the words you mention are nouns. :)

Comment: Related (more specific): [“Well” and “good” for how photographs come out](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/211/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Formally speaking, *good* is an adjective and *well* is an adverb.  So in formal speech or writing, you would want to maintain this distinction.

Informally, English speakers can often use an adjective in place of an adverb.  This is especially clear for words that take an *-ly* suffix to form an adverb.  For example: "that guy walks strange".

Even informally, this does not go the other way. We can't use words that are clearly adverbs as adjectives: "he's a strangely guy."

This is the same for *good* and *well*:

> - This thing works pretty good.  (Informally fine)
> - This thing works pretty well.  (Informally and formally fine)
> - He is a good speaker. (Informally and formally fine)
> - *He is a well speaker. (Bad anytime)

There is also a certain special situation, namely talking about health, where *well* and *good* have different nuances, but both can be used as adjectives.

> - I am well. (=healthy)
> - I am good. (can mean healthy, also "not evil", skilled, etc.)

Comment: "He is a well speaker" - perfectly fine! It means his profession is sitting in wells and speaking. Heh or as Steve said, a speaker who is currently healthy.

Comment: @Claudiu: Yes, I agree — and I said as much in my answer. (See the last section.)

Comment: I recall a Monty Python sketch with the line "He's not a well cat". Perfectly comprehensible, but funny because utterly unidiomatic. Though I think "not a well x" became something of a catchphrase afterwards.

Comment: Adjectives (at least some) get adverbed much more often in US than in UK usage.  “That works pretty good” and “She was walking real strange” are fine informal usage in many (most?) US dialects, but quite jarring to a British ear.

Answer (score 7):

*Good* is an adjective. It is used with nouns, e.g. "He is a good **dog**".

*Well* is the adverb form of *good*. It is used with verbs, e.g. "He **plays** the piano well".

Confusingly, *well* can also be an adjective, meaning *in good health*, e.g. "a well **person**" (someone who is not sick).

There are examples where exceptions to these may be used informally, e.g. "I'm **doing** good" (*good* with a verb).

Comment: It may be worth noting that "goodly" and "unwell" both go decidedly against the normal patterns [the former, despite the suffix, is an adjective; the latter, even though "well" is *usually* an adverb, is a negation only of the adjectival form].  Further, "doing good" may be an entirely correct construction if "good" is being used as a noun [e.g. so the phrase would mean meaning "contributing to the good of a community"]

Answer (score -1):

"Good" usually refers to qualitative aspect. For example: "She is a good woman."

"Well" refers to physical well-being. "She is well today."

If someone says, "she is good today", it may also imply that "she was bad yesterday"! Again, if we analyze antonyms of both the words, we find: good - bad ; well - unwell. "Good woman" means "not a bad woman," while "well woman" means "not a sick woman."

Comment: This post would be improved by explaining *why* you define the words this way, for example, by providing dictionary definition or examples in the wild. I encourage you take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.