# Which is more correct: well or good? within the context given:

Tags: sentence, adverbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between “good” and “well”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5174/what-is-the-difference-between-good-and-well)

"I work equally well as part of a team or as an independent researcher."

*or*

"I work equally good as part of a team or as an independent researcher."

Comment: I apologize for the duplication.

Comment: no need to apologize. Even though duplicate questions get closed, their existence helps to populate the "frequently asked questions" http://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=faq . The more duplicates of a question that are asked, the higher it appears on that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Well* is correct here.  You need an adverb to modify the verb *work*.

Answer (score 2):

"I work equally well", certainly.  "Good" is an adjective, "well" is an adverb.