# Is "the song matches so good" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between “good” and “well”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5174/what-is-the-difference-between-good-and-well)

Is *the song matches so good* grammatical? It was posted in the context of a video link, like a comment. It simply sounded weird to me, but I can't really explain why. I personally would rephrase it to *the song fits so well*.

Comment: Good is an adjective. Well is an adverb. See http://english.stackexchange.com/q/5174/24168 for more information. In this sentence, we want an adverb to modify "matches". So, the correct word is "well".

Comment: As grammatical as an "I am good" response to "How are you!"

Comment: If you can't really explain why, then there's a good chance you might be a good fit for our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners). We need a few more commitments from SE regulars to help make that site a reality.

Answer (score 1):

> The song matches so **well**

is the correct sentence. However, in

> The song matches so **good**

*good* is used as an adverb in place of *well*. This usage is chiefly American and informal.

Comment: What about the "so" used for emphasis?

Comment: @ Will Hunting ('s answer): _And_ labelled in your reference as a non-standard usage (in a sentence I feel is closer to the one asked about).