# Which is correct? "I do not feel good" or "I do not feel well"

Tags: vocabulary

I was reading through a few short stories when I realised that one of the stories had these two sentences:" I do not feel good" and "I do not feel well" I was quite puzzled and I would like to know if they are both correct. If they are different in anyway, please provide a specimen sentence for the two sentences.

Comment: You might find your question better answered at [ell.se]. [Good](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/good?q=good) vs [well](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/well?q=well)

Comment: You might also find an answer in this question: [What is the difference between “good” and “well”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5174/what-is-the-difference-between-good-and-well)

Comment: Say your fingertips are a bit numb.  When you try to use them to feel the surface of an object, you may say "I do not feel well"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I do not feel good* and *I do not feel well* are equivalent. They both indicate your well-being. *Well* and *good* both modify *feel*. However, you can use *feel good* in another construction like so:

> I do not feel good about the path I have taken.

Here, you are not expressing anything about your health, rather you are expressing how you are feeling about your interaction with something else, like "the path".

Comment: A related Ngram lends support to the claim that they're both frequently used ( http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=feel+so+well%2Cfeel+too+good&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share= ). _Good_ and _well_ are both (predicative) adjectives here (cf I feel _cold_). Often, a slight adjustment is made (_I don't feel too well_, _I don't feel so good_, _I don't feel well at all_) but this is only a matter of style, not a requirement.

Comment: I am a bit unclear about your explanation. Do you mean that "I don't feel good" usually conveys that the person is referring to his emotional state or how his day is going.While "I don't feel well" usually conveys that the person is referring to his physical state, that he is sick.

Comment: Usage: *good*, AmE; *well*, BrE.

Comment: @DavidToh Uh, no, David. The sentences are equivalent as they stand. However, my opinion is that the `feel good` version may be extended in the way I suggested while the other may not be.

Comment: for better perception of both i.e. good vs well [follow the link](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5174/what-is-the-difference-between-good-and-well), also mentioned above by  Matt Эллен

Comment: @Raghav Thanks buddy. @DavidToh David, the link that Raghav posted explains it very well and the point about `good` being an adjective and `well` being an adverb results in the kind of construction I explained.

Comment: @PankajSharma better way to thanks here may be upvote mine comment friend.