# How to reply to someone's welcome

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, american-english, speech

What should we say in reply to a person who welcomes us to a particular place, for example one says:

> You are welcome to ABC company.

or

> I welcome you to our home.

or

> Welcome Mr. Abc to this party.

Would "**Thank you!**" be the reply?

Comment: Yes; *thank you* and *thanks* are the most common and accepted responses in these scenarios.

Comment: Or you could give them a quizzical look and say "You talk funny." In your first example, that construction would almost never be used unless you were offering someone something you probably didn't want. In the second you would sound stilted beyond belief. And in the third, you're being ordered to do something, so no thanks would be in order.

Comment: @Robusto lol you are just Robust

Comment: "You talk *funnily*." maybe @Robusto? xD

Comment: @Neeku: Almost nobody ever says that in conversation. And those who do sound funny when they do say that.

Comment: Right @Robusto, but we both agree that "funny" is an adjective, while in that sentence, if we want to mention the manner of the verb, we must use an adverb, "funnily". Grammatical vs. common use. :-/

Comment: @Neeku: That is not the point. What I said was an example of a frozen trope, which means ordinary grammaar rules are suspended.

Comment: *grammar (damn typos)

Comment: @Robusto: Curiously (to me, anyway) OED doesn't explicitly recognise *adverbial* "funny" (they only apply the *adv* category to "funnily"). It's not obvious why they explicitly list, say, "loud" or "quick" as potentially adverbial usages, but not "funny". *"He talks funny/loud/quick/funnily/loudly/quickly"* are all similar, to me.

Comment: @Fumble: The same for *weird*, *strange*, etc.

Comment: Also, the same applies to other verbs, like *act*. "You're acting strange."

Comment: @Robusto: Or indeed, *"Don't talk daft!"*. I never heard anyone use the ***-ly*** form on that one either. There's a certain amount of choice with *loud, quick, strange*, but apparently not with *funny, daft*.

Comment: @Fumble: Check [Kosmonaut's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/5180/2303) regarding adjective/adverb substitution. I think that about nails it.

Comment: @Robusto: That's certainly highly relevant, but it doesn't say anything about why *some* adjectival forms seem to be actually *required* in "adverbial" contexts. Another one being *"Granddad always acts **silly** with the toddlers"*, where I can't imagine anyone using ***sillily*** (a "word" which my Google Chrome browser is highly suspicious of! :)

Comment: @Fumble: Well, in some cases, the suspected adverb is really an adjective. "Your car looks red" is a pretty exact parallel to "Granddad acts silly" in my view. You would never say "Your car looks redly," nor would you say "Grandpa acts sillily." This area still looks kind of gray (not "grayly") to me.

Comment: @Robusto: oic. Yeah, the specific *verb* may be highly relevant. But I think *look, seem, appear,* etc. are well and truly on one side of a dividing line that *act* rather more "straddles". I'm okay with either form in *Grandpa was acting strange/strangely*, but *Grandpa was looking strangely* doesn't work for me unless I add something like ***...at me*** to force the *look = peer* rather than *look = **appear*** interpretation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first two instances "Thank you" would be fine. In the third, "Hi, Mr. Abe" or applause.